# Order of references

Tags: academic-writing, citations, scientific-publishing

Suppose I have the following references to literature:

- Miller, H. (1999): …                          Referred to as: Miller
  (1999)
- Miller, F., & Smith, J. (2002): …             Referred to as: Miller
  & Smith (2002)
- Miller, A., & Smith, J. (2003): …             Referred to as: Miller
  & Smith (2003)
- Miller, B.,  Smith, J., & Jones, K. (2001): … Referred to as: Miller
  et al. (2001)
- Miller, B.,  Jones, K., & Smith, J. (2004): … Referred to as: Miller
  et al. (2004)

How to sort those entries?

“Logic” (?) says to first use

- Miller, A., & Smith, J. (2003): … Referred to as: Miller & Smith
  (2003)

because all authors are “Millers” but Arthur’s given name begins with the first letter of the alphabet.

- Miller, B.,  Jones, K., & Smith, J. (2004): … Referred to as: Miller
  et al. (2004)

would follow, because “B” comes after “A” and “Jones” before “Smith”,

- Miller, B.,  Smith, J., & Jones, K. (2001): … Referred to as: Miller
  et al. (2001)
- Miller, F., & Smith, J. (2002): … Referred to as: Miller & Smith
  (2002)

and

- Miller, H. (1999): … Referred to as: Miller (1999)

would follow.

On the other hand, practically would sort as follows:

- Miller, H. (1999): … Referred to as: Miller (1999)

because this is a “one author reference”.

- Miller, F., & Smith, J. (2002): … Referred to as: Miller & Smith
  (2002)

Before

- Miller, A., & Smith, J. (2003): … Referred to as: Miller & Smith
  (2003)

Because these are two-author references and “Miller & Smith (2002)” is chronologically before “Miller & Smith (2003)”. From the reference “Miller & Smith” the given names are not known to the reader (before looking in the references), thus sorting after the known year would make sense. Therefore also

- Miller, B.,  Smith, J., & Jones, K. (2001): … Referred to as: Miller
  et al. (2001)

would go before

- Miller, B.,  Jones, K., & Smith, J. (2004): … Referred to as: Miller
  et al. (2004)

Which sorting order is “better”/more common? Or is there another sort of ordering which makes more sense?!

There is no style guide, required format, standard or something like that for the planned publication.

Comment: Where is this being published? Have you asked to see if there are existing standards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the style guide you're following; different guides have different rules.

For Turabian / Chicago Style, the rules applicable are:

> A single-author entry precedes a multiauthor entry beginning with the
>   same name.

and

> Successive entries by two or more authors in which only the first
>   author’s name is the same are alphabetized according to the coauthors’
>   last names (regardless of how many coauthors there are).

These rules order your list; since every entry has a different set of authors, chronology doesn't come into it. The order you want (if you are following Chicago style) is:

```
Miller, H. (1999): … Referred to as: Miller (1999)
Miller, A., & Smith, J. (2003): … Referred to as: Miller & Smith (2003)
Miller, B., Jones, K., & Smith, J. (2004): … Referred to as: Miller et al. (2004)
Miller, B., Smith, J., & Jones, K. (2001): … Referred to as: Miller et al. (2001)
Miller, F., & Smith, J. (2002): … Referred to as: Miller & Smith (2002)
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the Turabian/Chicago Style. Where could I find information about possible other styles (and about how do they work, how common are they,...)?

Comment: There are lots - see the sidebar on the right hand side of this wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide ... usually a publication has a preference for one or another. Some have their own unique style guides. The important thing (as Lauren Ipsum pointed out in a comment to your question) is to use the one your publisher wants you to use.

Comment: Great comment! Could you include this in the answer? This additional info made me accept (and upvote) your answer.

Comment: can you please explain what does (s)he mean by sorting? In bibliography you can't have citations.